# Git log in PyCharm (JetBrains) IDE

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide

I understand that in the PyCharm Git log, each color represents consecutive commits.

I understand that a merge looks like that :

[image]

If they aren't FastForward merges. And like this if they are :

[image]

I don't understand what the color switches represent. Furthermore, I'm unsure of how to check the name associated with each branch. For example in this part I have some merges and ff merges without a descriptive headline is there any way to check the historical names of the branches merged?

[image]

I tried to find information on JetBrains' website, but I couldn't find enough guidance. I would greatly appreciate assistance, especially in understanding what happened in the last picture I uploaded, which is the least clear to me.

Comment: I edited in accordance. it helped me a bit but I'm still unsure as of the last picture for example.

Comment: What is unclear in the last picture? it just depicts some merge commits.

Comment: it was unclear to me how to find the historical names now i understand that you cant ... thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

> each color represents consecutive commits.

No, they repreent parallel unnamed branches.

> I don't understand what the color switches represent.

Branching and merging.

> how to check the name associated with each branch

There are no names associated with branches, otherwise you would see them in the graph.

> is there any way to check the historical names of the branches merged?

You could look at the merge commit messages or you could be able to find a repo where those branches are still named but in general no. They could even nor exist at all because you don't need to have a branch name to make a merge.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to check the historical names of the branches merged?

No.

This isn't specific to this particular git UI, it's a fundamental part of git's design. In some Version Control Systems, every commit "belongs to" a branch, and "creating a branch" is like creating a new container for commits to go into.

In git, **a branch is just a bookmark pointing at a commit** (in git jargon, a "commit ref"). A commit in git knows about its *parents* (one parent for a normal commit, two for a standard merge, other numbers in rare situations), but not its *children* (commits are immutable, so there would be no way to add extra children later). By naming the "current" commit on a particular branch, you can trace that branch *backwards*, following its parents as far back as you want.

When we say "commit A on branch B" in git, we're using a convenient for short-hand for "commit A is reachable by following the history of the commit pointed at by the ref B".

So the graphs you see in that tool, or any visualisation of git history, are constructed by starting at some "head" (e.g. the commit currently pointed at by a branch) and drawing either:

- A straight line if it has one parent (a normal commit, *including a fast-forward or squash merge*, which are not recorded in any special way)
- A branching into two (or more) lines if it has multiple parents (a merge commit)
- A combining from two lines into one if two commits have the same parent

Then simply repeat for every commit, making space to extend lines past each other so there's somewhere to put the text.

Note that this is effectively symmetrical, so if you want to read from oldest to newest, you can view "two commits with the same parent" as "branching", and "one commit with two parents" as "merging".

Example:

```
H
|
G
|\
| F
| |
| E
| |\ 
| | |
D | |
| | |
| | C
| | |
|/_/
B
|
A
```

What we can see for sure:

- Commit B has a parent A, and three children, C, D, and E
- Commit E has parents B and C, and child F
- Commit G has parents D and F, and child H

What we can guess:

- There were at some point three parallel branches; they probably had names, but those are not recorded anywhere in the history
- There may have been more, but they were fast-forwarded, squashed, or just never had commits; we have no trace of branches, only commits
- The three branches were created from commit B, which they all share
- On one branch someone created commit C
- That was then merged into another branch, creating E
- On the combined branch, someone created commit F
- Meanwhile, on the third branch someone created commit D
- The combined branch with C-E-F was merged into the branch with D, creating G
- Finally, commit H was created on top of that

Commit H is probably still pointed at by a branch name, like `main`, `master`, or `dev`, which is why we're looking at it.